# Use Python to export Excel column data when column isn't in first row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export

I need to pull data from a column based on the column header. My only problem is the input files aren't consistent and have the column in different locations and the data doesn't start on row one.

[image]

Above is an example excel file. I want to pull the data for Market. I've got this to work using panda if the data starts at a1, but I can't get it to pull the data if it doesn't start in the first position.

Comment: if you using pandas, it has `skiprows=` option...
`pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", skiprows = 10)`

Comment: you can also, choose columns to read, - plenty of examples online

Comment: The row and column for the start of the table are inconsistent. Sometimes the table starts on the 7th row sometimes it starts on the 10th row. Same with the column sometimes it's column B sometimes it's D.

Comment: in this case I would import without skipping rows, and drop empty rows after, use the first row as a header later

Answer (score 1):

How about you use this just after you pd.read_excel() statement ?

```
df=df.dropna(how='all',axis='columns').dropna(how='all',axis='rows')
```

You can then set the first row as header:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df
```